# PDF of $1/Z^2$ if $Z$ is $N(0,1)$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Suppose $Z /~ N(0,1)$ with probability density function $$f(z)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left[-\dfrac{z^2}{2}\right]$$ where $-\infty<z<\infty$. Find the pdf of $Y=1/Z^2$.

I know that $Y=1/Z^2$ isn't one-to-one. So I can use the transformation method. Thus I am left with the cdf method or the moment generating function method to find the pdf of $Y=1/Z^2$. I have tried both ways but I get complicated integrals. Can I get some assistance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $V = Z^2 \sim \chi^2(1)$, i.e., 
$$
f_{V}(v) = \frac{e^{-v/2}}{\sqrt{\pi v}}, \quad v>0
$$
now, you can use the transformation $g(V)= 1/V=W$, where $ g^{-1}(W) = 1/W $, thus
$$
f_W(w)= f_V(g^{-1}(w))\left|\frac{\partial}{\partial w} g^{-1}(w)\right| = \frac{e^{-1/(2w)}}{\sqrt{\pi/w}}\frac{1}{w^2}\, =\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi} w^{3/2}}\exp\{-1/(2w)\}, \,\, w>0.
$$